# Scroll table upwards or downwards using up and down button

Tags: php, javascript, html, scroll

I want to create a banner scrolling function for my homepage. I am not too sure of which programming language to use here. I want to code something similar to: http://www.squidfaceandthemeddler.com/. But I want the footer to remain at the same position while the user scroll the table. Is it possible to get that result? I have create a simple tables and 2 images for the user to click on

here is my code for the tables:

```
<div id="banner" style="height:750px; width:600px; overflow:scroll;" > 
    <table width="750px" height="600px"> 
    <tr> 
    <td><a href="sale_1.php"><img src="banner1.png"/></a></td> 
    </tr> 
    </table> 

    <table width="750px" height="600px"> 
    <tr> 
    <td><a href="sale_2.php"><img src="banner2.png"/></a></td> 
    </tr> 
    </table> 

    <table width="750px" height="600px"> 
    <tr> 
    <td><a href="sale_3.php"><img src="banner3.png"/></a></td> 
    </tr> 
    </table> 
</div>
```

and this is the upwards and downwards button for the scrolling:

```
<table width="750px" height="30px"> 
<tr> 
<td align="right"><img src="images/up_arrow.png"/><img src="images/down_arrow.png"/></td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: hmmm... A site that prevent right click... bad design, don't copy that part ;)

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle and someone will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the contents inside two div tags you can use CSS to clip the
outer div and "scroll" the inner div by scripting its CSS "top" value, thus:

```
<html><head><style>
#contents{ 
 position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100px; height: auto;}
 #scrollable{ overflow: hidden; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px
solid black;
 }
</style>
<script>
var t = 0;

function up()
{
 t += 10;

 with(document.getElementById("contents"))
 {
   if (t > 0)
    t = 0;

 if(style)
    style.top = t + "px";
 else
  setAttribute("style", "top: " + t + "px");
}
}

function down()
{
 t -= 10;

with(document.getElementById("contents"))
{
  if(t < -clientHeight)
      t = -clientHeight;

  if(style)
       style.top = t + "px";
  else
       setAttribute("style", "top: " + t + "px");
  }
 }
</script></head>
   <body><table><tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="up()">up</a></td>
   <td rowspan="2"><div id="scrollable">
     <div id="contents">scrolling content scrolling content scrolling content
        scrolling content scrolling content scrolling content scrolling content
        scrolling content scrolling content scrolling content scrolling content
   </div></div> 
       </td></tr><tr><td>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="down()">down</a></td></tr></table>
    </body></html>
```

take the help of this edit your code

Comment: But I have to achieve it using the upwards and downwards button.

Comment: @Naveen Kumar Yadav How to add the scrolling effect?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jquery scrolltop: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/. I would fix the tables width to a certain height, like you already did and then:

```
$('#buttonUpID').click(function () {
    var currentScrollTop = $('body').scrollTop();
    $('body').scrollTop(currentScrollTop - 600);
});

$('#buttonDownID').click(function () {
    var currentScrollTop = $('body').scrollTop();
    $('body').scrollTop(currentScrollTop + 600);
});
```